# Difference in Probability when 2 numbered cards are picked together and when 2 cards picked one after the other.

Tags: probability

What is the difference between the probability for the following two cases
There are $50$ cards numbered from $1$ to $50$. Odds of picking an odd card when:

$1)$.Two cards are picked together.

$2)$.Two cards are picked one after the other.

Are they different?How so

Comment: They should be identical, assuming that the cards are picked **without replacement**. Otherwise, if (in the second scenario) the first card is returned to the deck before the second card is picked, then the result will be different.

Comment: What would be the answer for the question then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In either case, we will simplify our calculations by finding the probability of the **complement**; that is, we will find the probability that both cards are even (instead of at least one of them being odd), then subtract this from $1$.

Suppose that the two cards are picked **with replacement**. Then we are **independently** picking each card. Note that there are $25$ even cards ($2,4,6,...,50$) out of a total of $50$ cards. Thus, we obtain a probability of:
$$
1-\dfrac{25}{50} \cdot \dfrac{25}{50} = 1-\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 = 1-\dfrac{1}{4}=\boxed{\dfrac{3}{4}}
$$

On the other hand, suppose that the cards are picked **without replacement**. Then picking the second card will **depend** on how the first card was picked. After picking an even card, there will be $25-1=24$ even cards leftover to be chosen from a total of $50-1=49$ possible cards. Thus, we obtain a probability of:
$$
1-\dfrac{25}{50} \cdot \dfrac{24}{49} = 1-\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \dfrac{24}{49} = 1-\dfrac{12}{49}=\boxed{\dfrac{37}{49}}
$$

Comment: i think the question is about getting at least 1 odd card, not 2.

Comment: @csharpler You're right. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are picking without replacement. Whether your fingers touch the cards absolutely simultaneously (if that is possible), or within a millisecond of each other, or with a separation of a day or two clearly should make no difference to the probability.

There are two possible meanings to "pick an odd card": (i) pick at least one odd card or (ii) pick exactly one odd card.

For (i), the probability is $1$ minus the probability the two cards are both even. Here it can be useful to imagine we are picking one at a time. The probability the first card is even is $\frac{25}{50}$. **Given** that the first card is even, the probability the second card is even is $\frac{24}{49}$. Thus the probability that at least one is odd is 
$$1-\frac{25}{50}\cdot\frac{24}{49}.$$

Let us find the probability that both cards are even another way, that does not involve order. There are $\binom{50}{2}$ equally likely ways to pick two cards. And there are $\binom{25}{2}$ ways to pick two even cards. So the probability both cards are even is $\dfrac{\binom{25}{2}}{\binom{50}{2}}$. It follows that the probability that at least one of the two cards is odd is 
$$1-\frac{\binom{25}{2}}{\binom{50}{2}}.$$
A calculation will show (no surprise!) that the two answers we have obtained are the same.

If we interpret the problem, less naturally, as (ii), the probability of exactly one odd, the same sort of reasoning as the one in the first solution to (i)  yields
$$\frac{25}{50}\cdot\frac{25}{49}+ \frac{25}{50}\cdot\frac{25}{49}.$$

The second counting approach yields
$$\frac{\binom{25}{1}\binom{25}{1}}{\binom{50}{2}}.$$